# sql query to find specific entries based on date range

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, date-arithmetic, having-clause

I have a database with a table containing the history of the login times of all accounts. The table includes columns USERID and LOGIN_DATE. I want to find those users who have not logged in for over 60 days, so an SQL query that says

Find users who have a login date which was greater than 60 days ago, but have no entry for any date more recently than 60 days ago

Can anyone suggest how I would do this ?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You could use aggregation, and filter on users whose maximum login date is older than 60 days:

```
select userid
from mytable
group by userid
having max(login_date) < current_date - interval '60' day
```

You did not tell which database you are using, so this uses standard date arithmetics. You might need to adapt that to your actual database (all major databases have alternatives for this).

---

Now the question was tagged Oracle. The above would work; you might want to truncate the time portion of the date to check on entire days. And if you want to *display* the last login, just add the aggregate function to the `select` clause:

```
select userid, max(login_date) last_login_date
from mytable
group by userid
having max(login_date) < trunc(current_date) - interval '60' day
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select userid
from t
group by userid
having max(logindate) < trunc(sysdate) - interval '60' day;
```

Date/time functions are notoriously database-specific, so the exact syntax for the having clause might depend on your database.

Comment: This is an Oracle database, so I know that the date is referred to by SYSDATE

Comment: I have tried this query, it produced a list of userids, but I also need the logindate to be included. If I enter "select userid, logindate...' the result is "not a GROUP BY expression".   If I try "group by userid, logindate", I get every entry in the table for logindate < 60 days, and it does not exclude userids which have logged in more recently

Answer (score 0):

Following can be a solution

```
select USERID, min(login_date) mind, max(login_date) maxd
from Logins
group by UserId
having max(login_date) < dateadd(d,-60,getdate())
```

Comment: The suggestion from Eralper gave me what I was looking for. thanks. I dont have enough rep to vote for it